# Bluetooth not write scanning using HCI

Tags: bluetooth, embedded, stack

I am trying to implement Bluetooth on an existing embedded device.  The controller I’m using is the LS Research TiWi-uB2, which uses the Ti CC2564 dual mode IC.  The host is a LPC2378 microcontroller.  The device needs to be discoverable by other devices (Android devices & PCs for the moment).  There is no ready made BT stack for this device which suits me needs (cost, static memory allocation, memory size) so I’m writing my own stack.

Going through Volume 2 Part E of the specification I eventually got meaningful communication on the HCI, but the device does not ever appear to be ‘discoverable’ by anything else.  At this point I’m only using the BR/EDR features rather than the LE features.

Here is a debug dump of the HCI interface (including the UART packet types):

```
BT_Reset
Tx: 0x01 0x03 0x0C 0x00
Rx: 0x04 0x0E 0x04 0x01 0x03 0x0C 0x00
Device info
Tx: 0x01 0x01 0x10 0x00
Rx: 0x04 0x0E 0x0C 0x01 0x01 0x10 0x00 0x06 0x00 0x00 0x06 0x0D 0x00 0x0F 0x1B
Local supported commands
Tx: 0x01 0x02 0x10 0x00
Rx: 0x04 0x0E 0x44 0x01 0x02 0x10 0x00 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0x03 0xCE 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF
Local supported features
Tx: 0x01 0x03 0x10 0x00
Rx: 0x04 0x0E 0x0C 0x01 0x03 0x10 0x00 0xFF 0xFE 0x2D 0xFE 0xDB 0xFF 0x7B 0x87
Get device address
Tx: 0x01 0x09 0x10 0x00
Rx: 0x04 0x0E 0x0A 0x01 0x09 0x10 0x00 0x81 0xA6 0xD3 0x2F 0x18 0x00
Address: 00 18 2F D3 A6 81
Read buffer size
Tx: 0x01 0x05 0x10 0x00
Rx: 0x04 0x0E 0x0B 0x01 0x05 0x10 0x00 0xFD 0x03 0xB4 0x04 0x00 0x04 0x00
ACL len = 1021
Write buffer size
Tx: 0x01 0x33 0x0C 0x07 0xFC 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
Rx: 0x04 0x0E 0x04 0x01 0x33 0x0C 0x00
Write local name
Tx: 0x01 0x13 0x0C 0x08 0x42 0x54 0x5F 0x54 0x65 0x73 0x74 0x00
Rx: 0x04 0x0E 0x04 0x01 0x13 0x0C 0x00
Read class of device
Tx: 0x01 0x23 0x0C 0x00
Rx: 0x04 0x0E 0x07 0x01 0x23 0x0C 0x00 0x14 0x01 0x08
Write class of device
Tx: 0x01 0x24 0x0C 0x03 0x14 0x01 0x08
Rx: 0x04 0x0E 0x04 0x01 0x24 0x0C 0x00
Write scan enabled
Tx: 0x01 0x1A 0x0C 0x01 0x03
Rx: 0x04 0x0E 0x04 0x01 0x1A 0x0C 0x00
Finished
```

I can also do link inquiry:

```
Tx: 0x01 0x01 0x04 0x05 0x33 0x8B 0x9E 0x0A 0x0A
Rx: 0x04 0x0F 0x04 0x00 0x01 0x01 0x04
…
Rx: 0x04 0x01 0x01 0x00
```

But it does not find any devices.

I’m sure I’m missing something fairly obvious out, but can’t see what it might be.  I can't see that the CC2564 needs to be specially treated to run in BR/EDR mode, and all the defaults seem reasonable.

## Update

The module needs an initialization script (aka 'service pack').  See https://code.google.com/p/btstack/wiki/MSP430GettingStarted under 'Init Scripts'. The good news is that with the script the module is now discoverable.  The bad news is that according to LS Research my own stack would not be Bluetooth SIG complaint - I would have to use the Bluetopia stack.  It seems that everything is geared heavily to using the Ti processor.
At this point I'll have to wait until the BR/EDR/BLE modules with a higher level interface come on line.

Comment: Your commands are reasonable.  Any evidence the RF is working?  Antenna connected?

Comment: It is the TiWi-uB2 EM Board, so the antenna is part of the circuit and looks ok (I just checked the jumpers and made sure).  I've also tested the slow clock with an oscilloscope (turns out that the HCI does not work without the slow clock in any case).  Once as the result of an inquiry I did receive the address of my laptop Bluetooth (but could not reproduce it again).

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth compliance is only needed, when you are using public profiles (SPP for example), or when you expose your device in a connectable manner for other devices in public (like headsets or keyboards). Shortly, qualification is only needed if you are selling your device on global market as a "Bluetooth" device (so you can use the logo)...at least in my understanding...

And the service pack does not contain any part of the stack, so its completely royalty free.

And there are no Bluetooth specific operations (even discovery) permitted before loading the service pack according to this document:
[cc256x guide](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC256x_Testing_Guide)